# Java - Console on an Applet

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to create a text-based game in Java similar to Zork and put it on a web server after I'm done and so I have decided to make the program an applet. My question is this: How do I display and input strings that are normally displayed through `System.out.println` and `System.in`? I know that I can create a JPanel and display text through a JTextArea but I want the console to be emulating a terminal like the one I am currently using shown here:

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7082/6879721298_323e72cc92_z.jpg

Is there any way to add a frame that will display the emulator inside of it or incorporate a console to display the strings outputted by the `System.out.println`?

Comment: *"put it on a web server after I'm done and so I have decided to make the program an applet."*  Poor decision.  The best user experience for an 'app. from a web site' is to launch a frame (free floating) from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Applets are harder to develop and deploy than a JWS app., and the user experience is not as nice.

Comment: If I install Web Start, does that mean that anyone who connects to the website has to have the Web Start downloaded in order to see the program? And also, does that mean I don't have to change any code for the current program? Thanks.

Comment: If you understand the term 'rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) desktop applications', then the answer to both your questions should be findable in the linked document.  Did you read it & follow all the links (and read them) in just 3 minutes, or are you asking me questions that could be answered in the linked documents ***instead of reading them?*** :/

Comment: Ok. I've just read the document through. Is there a way to embed the program in a website without using an applet or having users to download the application through webstart like in Zork? The link below is a Java applet but I am wondering if there is a work-around for displaying applications directly.                                http://pot.home.xs4all.nl/infocom/zork1.html

Comment: You seems to be presuming an embedded applet is not downloaded.  ***It is.***  Launching a JWS app. is just as fast (faster, when you consider the number of times that applet deployments don't work because of the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to add a frame that will display the emulator inside of it or incorporate a console to display the strings outputted by the `System.out.println`?

It is technically possible to redirect the system `in`, `err` & `out` streams, but note that it requires a trusted app. (digitally signed by the developer, user clicks 'OK' when prompted at the scary dialog) to do it.  OTOH it would be better to design<sup>1</sup> a different version of the software for a GUI that puts the output directly into a text area or similar (for output) & accepts it from a text field (for input).

Another alternative for a sand-boxed app. (very kludgy, but possible), is to log the output to the anonymous logger.  Add a log handler to retrieve that output and display it.  Using logging does solve app. output, but not user input.

1. Or rather, the ***best*** design would be to have the logic independent of input/output device, and use that logic in both command line & GUI versions.

---

I now note the screen-shot says 'Dragon Console'.  How does that differ in functionality from the Windows 'Command Prompt'?

Comment: Well, for one, Dragon Console is implemented in the actual program so there is no need to go into command prompt and open stuff up in order to use the program. Also, I originally thought that the use of Dragon Console would work as an applet as it is written in java but I am not too sure how to put it up as an applet.

Comment: Let's take a pause for a moment to clarify something.  What is Dragon Console?  Link to the site where you got it.